# Vanishing of cohomology on the fiber and base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a Noetherian scheme and $\mathcal F$ a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb P^n\times S$, flat over $S$. Let $s_0\in S$ and suppose that $\mathcal F$ induces a coherent sheaf $\mathcal F_{s_0}$ on $\mathbb P^n_{s_0}=p_2^{-1}(s_0)$. If $H^{i+1}(\mathbb P^n, \mathcal F_{s_0})=0$, is it true that there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $s_0$ such that for any $s\in U$ the natural map $R^i p_{2,*}(\mathcal F)\otimes k(s)\to H^i(\mathbb P^n_s, \mathcal F_s)$ is an isomorphism? Equivalently, is $R^i p_{2,*}(\mathcal F)$ locally free in $U$? It seems that Mumford uses it in his Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface, but I don't know why this should be true. I'm especially interested in the case $i=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the statement you are looking for.

**Theorem.** Let $f:X \to S$ be a proper morphism of Noetherian schemes and $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf over $X$, flat over $S$. If $s_0\in S$ is such that $H^1(f^{-1}(s_0),\mathcal{F}_{s_0})=0$, then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $s_0$ such that $f_*\mathcal{F}|_U$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_U$-module.

This is an application of Grothendieck's results on cohomology and base change in EGA III. See, for instance, Theorem 12.11 in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.

Assuming this "Cohomology and Base Change Theorem", the proof goes roughly as follows. The condition $H^1(f^{-1}(s_0),\mathcal{F}_{s_0})=0$ implies that $R^1f_*\mathcal{F} \otimes k(s_0) = 0$. Using that $R^1f_*\mathcal{F}$ is coherent and Nakayama's lemma, we deduce that there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $s_0$ such that $R^1f_*\mathcal{F}$ vanishes over $U$. In particular, $R^1f_*\mathcal{F}$ is locally free over $U$. By the Cohomology and Base Change Theorem applied to $i=1$, this implies that the natural map
$$
f_*\mathcal{F} \otimes k(s) \to H^0(f^{-1}(s),\mathcal{F}_{s})
$$
is an isomorphism for every $s\in U$. This last fact implies that $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is locally free over $U$ (by the same theorem, "applied to $i=0$")

Another nice reference for all of these is the following preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.7320.pdf.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the statement of the theorem in Hartshorne incorrectly.